# Need Help in Binding data to Treeview using mvc.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I m trying to bind the data to treeview using mvc.net, and bootstrap.  According to the levels of parentdata(table Name in example) it should bind  data to treeview , example purpose i have provided below query for data.

I m using Bootstrap for this treeview using mvc.net.

Requirement:- From Parent table all "level" columns 1 are parent, after 1 immediate levels are child for 1 upto next 1.

Example:-

I want to display data in tree view in the below format.

-1002(parent)- level 1 in table parentdata

```
->1110(child for 1002) level 2
```

-1211(parent) level 1 in table parentdata

```
->1222(Child for 1211) level 2 

->1224(child for 1211) level 3

->1224 (child for 1211) level 4
```

-1332 (parent) level 1 in table parentdata

```
->1334 (child for 1332 ) level 1
```

etc...

Sql Query :-

```
create table parentdata(
[parentdataid] int,
[datavalue] int,
[level] int
)
GO
insert into parentdata
select 1001,10,1 UNION 
select 1001,11,1 UNION 
select 1001,13,1 UNION 
select 1002,1222,1 UNION 
select 1222,1223,2 UNION 
select 1223,1224,3 UNION 
select 1224,1225,4 UNION 
select 1332,1334,1 UNION 
select 1334,1335,2 UNION 
select 1335,1336,3 UNION 
select 1900,1800,1 UNION 
select 1800,1801,2 UNION 
select 1801,1802,3 UNION 
select 1803,1804,4 UNION 
select 1804,1805,5 UNION 
select 1805,1806,6 UNION 
select 1806,1807,7 UNION 
select 1450,1212,1 UNION 
select 1211,1050,1 UNION 
select 10220,10234,1 UNION 
select 10235,10239,2 UNION 
select 10239,10221,3 UNION 
select 10221,10232,4 UNION 
select 10232,10292,5 UNION 
select 10110,1110,1 UNION 
select 1110,11109,2 UNION 
select 11109,11121,3 
GO
select * from parentdata
```

so data is in parentdata table format, using this parentdata table i need to bind data to tree view, below is the code i want to use

CSS Code:-

```
 <style>
    .tree {
        min-height: 20px;
        padding: 19px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #fbfbfb;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }

        .tree li {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
            position: relative;
        }

            .tree li::before, .tree li::after {
                content: '';
                left: -20px;
                position: absolute;
                right: auto;
            }

            .tree li::before {
                border-left: 1px solid #999;
                bottom: 50px;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0;
                width: 1px;
            }

            .tree li::after {
                border-top: 1px solid #999;
                height: 20px;
                top: 25px;
                width: 25px;
            }

            .tree li span {
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #999;
                border-radius: 5px;
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 3px 8px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .tree li.parent_li > span {
                cursor: pointer;
            }

        .tree > ul > li::before, .tree > ul > li::after {
            border: 0;
        }

        .tree li:last-child::before {
            height: 30px;
        }

        .tree li.parent_li > span:hover, .tree li.parent_li > span:hover + ul li span {
            background: #eee;
            border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
            color: #000;
        }
</style>
```

View  Code (for example purpose):-

```
 <div class="tree well">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span><i class="icon-folder-open"></i> Parent</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Great Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great great Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great great Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span><i class="icon-folder-open"></i> Parent2</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Script used in View Page:-

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
        $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
            var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
            if (children.is(":visible")) {
                children.hide('fast');
                $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
            } else {
                children.show('fast');
                $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

using the above code how can i bind data from parentdata table in tree format with levels.

thanks